# django - logging edit event - need to get id of logged in user

Tags: django, logging, django-models

I've a product-stock model as given below.

```
TRANSACTION_TYPE=(('I','Stock In'),('O','Stock Out'))
class Stock(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey('product.Product', blank=False,null=False)
    date=models.DateField(blank=False, null=False,)
    quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    ttype=models.CharField(max_length=1,verbose_name="Transaction type",choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE, blank=False, db_index=True)
```

I need to log the update activity on this model, along with the id of the user who updated it.

```
ACTIONS=(('EC','Edit Category'),
        ('EG','Edit Group'),
        ('EP','Edit Product'),
        ('ES','Edit Stock'))
class MyLog(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User, blank=False)
    action= models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ACTIONS, null=False,blank=False)
    date=models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now=True)
    data = JSONField()
```

I've the added following code to the Stock model.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Stock, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.pk != None :
            self.__important_fields = ['product','date', 'quantity', 'ttype', ]
            for field in self.__important_fields:
                setattr(self, '__original_%s' % field, getattr(self, field))
                field_name='__original_%s' % field

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk != None :
        print("Editing")
        flag=False
        log=MyLog(user=?,action='ES')
        log.data=[]
        for field in self.__important_fields:
            original=getattr(self, '__original_%s' % field)
            if original != getattr(self, field):
                flag=True

            log.data.append({field : str(original)})

        if flag:
            log.save()
    else:
        print("Adding")
    super(Stock, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works, when I hard code a user object into the line log=MyLog(user=**?**,action='ES').

I need to log the id of the user who performed this edit operation.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to pass the logged in user id from a view.

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I finally achieved my goal.

Instead of logging the event from the model, **I switched my code to  the forms**.

Here's my final code.

**mylog app model**

```
ACTIONS=(('EC','Edit Category'),
        ('EG','Edit Group'),
        ('EP','Edit Product'),
        ('ES','Edit Stock'))
class MyLog(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False)
    model_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    action= models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ACTIONS, null=False,blank=False)
    date=models.DateTimeField(blank=False, auto_now=True)
    old_data = JSONField(default=None)
    new_data = JSONField(default=None)
```

**stock app - update view**

```
class UpdateStock(UpdateView):
    model=Stock
    form_class=UpdateStockForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super( UpdateStock, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user_id': self.request.user.id})
        return kwargs
```

**stock app - update form**

```
class UpdateStockForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self,pk= None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id=kwargs.pop('user_id')

        super(UpdateStockForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UpdateStockForm, self).clean()
        quantity = cleaned_data.get('quantity')
        date= cleaned_data.get('date')

        priv_quantity=self.instance.quantity
        priv_date=self.instance.date

        if priv_quantity!=quantity or priv_date != date:
            #log!   
        log=MyLog(user=auth.models.User.objects.get(pk=self.user_id),action='ES', model_id=self.instance.id) 
            log.old_data=[]
            log.old_data.append({'date' : str(priv_date), 'quantity':priv_quantity })

            log.new_data=[]
            log.new_data.append({ 'date' : str(date), 'quantity':quantity })

        log.save()

    return cleaned_data
```